# Stream the most recent data in cassandra with spark streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, bigdata

I continuously have data being written to cassandra from an outside source.

Now, I am using spark streaming to continuously read this data from cassandra with the following code:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))

val cassandraRDD = ssc.cassandraTable("keyspace2", "feeds")


val dstream = new ConstantInputDStream(ssc, cassandraRDD)


dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
 println("\n"+rdd.count())
}

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
sc.stop()
```

However, the following line:

`val cassandraRDD = ssc.cassandraTable("keyspace2", "feeds")`

takes the entire table data from cassandra every time. Now just the newest data saved into the table.

What I want to do is have spark streaming read only the latest data, ie, the data added after its previous read.

How can I achieve this? I tried to Google this but got very little documentation regarding this.

I am using `spark 1.4.1`, `scala 2.10.4` and `cassandra 2.1.12`.

Thanks!

EDIT:

The suggested duplicate question (asked by me) is NOT a duplicate, because it talks about connecting spark streaming and cassandra and this question is about streaming only the latest data. BTW, streaming from cassandra IS possible by using the code I provided. However, it takes the entire table every time and not just the latest data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to connect spark streaming with cassandra?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993290/how-to-connect-spark-streaming-with-cassandra)

Comment: Streaming from Cassandra is not possible at the moment. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993290/how-to-connect-spark-streaming-with-cassandra

Comment: ha. I just noticed that it was you who asked that question. The answer has not changed yet, I'm afraid.

Comment: That question (asked by me) is NOT a duplicate, because it talks about connecting spark streaming and cassandra and this question is about streaming only the latest data. BTW, streaming from cassandra IS possible by using the code I provided. However, it takes the entire table every time and not just the latest data.

Comment: I don't think there is out-of-the box solution for a problem you described, because it is require additional information in time-series manner which Cassandra doesn't maintain. I think you can use CQL queries bounded by 'last processed time' instead of 'cassandraTable'. But then you should properly alter your data-structures: https://academy.datastax.com/demos/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling

Comment: Although i'm also considering this a duplicate, you could potentially append a .where clause onto the RDD's you are fore-eaching as long as the underlying table is spaced by time. The trick is how do you update that where clause on a per batch basis. There I think the best you can do is to use the .foreach( time, RDD => ) or transform( time,RDD =>) and use the batch window timing to do your slice.

Answer (score 1):

There will be some low-level work on Cassandra that will allow notifying external systems (an indexer, a Spark stream etc.) of new mutations incoming to Cassandra, read this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8844